# LINQ to SQL and Silverlight 5 saving edited records throws exceptions

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql, xaml, azure, silverlight-5.0

I've been ruining Christmas with this problem. We have this website which was BUILT using Silverlight 4 and clients have asked us to upgrade it to Silverlight 5. I had first encountered a problem during deployment in azure due to RIA related DLLs not being published to web folder because CopyLocal values were set to false causing azure deployment to be aborted. So we had solve this by simply setting CopyLocal values to true. But luckily we had encountered a much more rare problem finding out that all entities in our project which uses DBML files turns our screen to pure white whenever updating records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of hard time which included a painful christmas.. We had fix this problem(THANK YOU LORD). Thanks to these link http://forums.silverlight.net/t/234553.aspx/1